# Distribute Single Page Application as native desktop software

Tags: javascript, browser, single-page-application

Is it possible to pack s single page application (its JavaScript files and images and all the assets) so that it can be distributed as a native 
**desktop** application? Like having an instance of Chrome without any button that just runs your application offline.
I've used software that seems to be crafted like that, for example TweetDeck by Twitter gives me the impression of being just the web-version of TweetDeck packed in some way to run in a context that is not your standard browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) (previously Node WebKit) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

There's [NW.js](http://nwjs.io).
To package nodejs / html apps on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by implementing a headless browser application.

There is an open source web browser engine here https://www.webkit.org/.

You incorporate it in a native application and parse the source files.

The webkit documentation presumably contains the specifics, have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Very much possible and all HTML5 apps are doing that, all your need is this:
https://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my post. I meant *desktop* applications, Cordova is for mobile ones.